# Is there any way to find the resized height/width of an image inside of a UIImageView with AspectFit set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get the `image.size.h` and `image.size.w` of the `UIImage` inside of an `UIImageView` with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` on.

I want the **resized** `UIImage` size, not the original image size.

Is it possible to get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calculate it by yourself:

```
//Your image
UIImage *image;
//Your imageView;
UIImageView *imageView;
int width, height;
float aspectRatio;
if (image.size.height > image.size.width)
{
    height = imageView.frame.size.height;
    aspectRatio = image.size.height / height;
    width = image.size.width / aspectRatio;
}
else
{
    width = imageView.frame.size.width;
    aspectRatio = image.size.width / width;
    height = image.size.height / aspectRatio;
}
```

Comment: I believe this will only work for squared image views. For example; an image view that is 320 x 416. An image could be 640 x 820. This would get scaled down and the new Width would be 320 whereas the height would be a little off 416 - not the full height of the image view. I am working on a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(79, 84);//set the width and height
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
           [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
           UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This works for sure and don't forget to import QuartzCore FrameWork..

Have a Happy Coding (^_^)....